# MenuInflator causing app to crash in certain phones (Tecno, Redmi Note 4)

Tags: java, android

I have an app in the play store that runs well on most phones. Recently I got complaints that it crashed when trying to install and open it in certain phones like Tecno, Redmi note 4. When looking at the crash report it points to the menu inflator line. The error states that there is no resource. The crash report is shown below.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0d0061
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:220)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2134)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:764)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:51)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:505)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:532)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:207)
at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:129)
at com.manatec.tpmsdisplay.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:473)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3403)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

When I looked into the source code (MainActivity.java:473) this the line

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

The main.xml file is present in the res/menu/ folder. But I am not sure why this error occurs. Any ideas where to start debugging this?.

Comment: This may happen when the R.java is not updated and it is not built correctly. Have you tried cleaning your project and rebuilding it?

Comment: Yes. I tried it. No success.